# How to temporarily disable button after click in Xamarin Forms even when navigating through the app?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am making a voting app and I want the user to be allowed to vote just one time/day. I have a main page and on this page, multiple buttons navigating to different pages (where the user can vote).On the voting "page" I have a button that when is pressed, it uploads the vote into a database, and after it is disabled for some time. However, if I go back and forth (voting page -> main page -> voting page) the button is once again enabled. How can I solve this, so wherever I navigate the button will remain disabled? I write down the code that I use to disable the button on the voting page, but as I said, whenever I leave the page the button will be enabled again.

```
public void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Timer aTimer = new Timer();
               myButton.IsEnabled = false;    
               aTimer.Interval = 5000; //ms
               aTimer.Enabled = true;
               aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;

       }

       public void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
       {
           Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { myButton.IsEnabled = true; });
       }
```

The Xaml definition of the button.

```
<ImageButton 
x:Name="myButton"
Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" >
```

Comment: you need to store some sort of value indicating that they have voted today

Comment: how would this value help me? or what should I do with it? I am a noobie in xamarin development so I don't really know how would this value help me ?

Comment: if they have already voted today disable the button.  I'm not sure what good the timer is if the idea is to prevent them from voting more than once per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to store data when leaving page using Navigation, if yes, I suggest you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android) to save current user data.

For MainPage:

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page15());
    }
```

For VotePage:

```
 public partial class Page15 : ContentPage
{  
    public DateTime dt;
    public Page15()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
        DateTime currentdate = DateTime.Now;

        bool haskey = Preferences.ContainsKey("user1");
        if(haskey)
        {
            string date = Preferences.Get("user1", "");
            if (date != null)
            {
                dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                TimeSpan timediff = currentdate - dt;

                if(timediff.Seconds<10)
                {
                    btnvote.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }             
        }           
    }

    private void btnvote_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        dt = DateTime.Now;

        //save count into database or local
        btnvote.IsEnabled = false;

    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        string clickdate = dt.ToString();
        Preferences.Set("user1", clickdate);
    }
}
```

In my code, I disable Button within 10 seconds of voting, you can use  timediff.Days;timediff.Minutes to change datetime difference.